# Cannot convert time.Now() to a string

Tags: go

I have this struct:

```
// Nearby whatever
type Nearby struct {
    id          int    `json:"id,omitempty"`
    me          int    `json:"me,omitempty"`
    you         int    `json:"you,omitempty"`
    contactTime string `json:"contactTime,omitempty"`
}
```

and then I call this:

```
strconv.Itoa(time.Now())
```

like so:

```
s1 := Nearby{id: 1, me: 1, you: 2, contactTime: strconv.Itoa(time.Now())}
```

but it says:

> ```
> > cannot use time.Now() (type time.Time) as type int in argument to
> > strconv.Itoa
> ```

does anyone know what that's about? I am trying to convert an int to a string here.

Comment: You're trying to convert int to string but [`time.Now()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Now) doesnt return an int.

Comment: `time.Now().Unix()` will return you an int64 epoch. Go is a strongly-typed language. That's why `Itoa` won't accept `time.Time`, the type of the `Now()`. The compiler won't cast anything unless it's untyped constant/literal.

Comment: What is the type of time.Now()? why is it hard to figure out what that return type is?

Comment: @MrCholo the type of time.Now() is `time.Time` (as in Time itself is a type). We can check it via the ff Go code `fmt.Printf("the type of time is %T", time.Now())`.

Comment: It's a `time.Time`, not sure how it is hard, as even the compiler tells you `cannot use time.Now() (type time.Time)`

Comment: Please refer to documentation of standard library to figure out return types. In this case, you can find it at: https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Now

Comment: I wonder why it's hard to find the return type for a call with an editor for a statically typed language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> does anyone know what that's about? I am trying to convert an int to a string here.

Time type is not equivalent to an int. If your need is a string representation, type `Time` has a `String()` method.

Sample code below (also available as a runnable Go Playground [snippet](https://play.golang.org/p/RK215FlalGB)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

// Nearby whatever
type Nearby struct {
    id          int
    me          int
    you         int
    contactTime string
}

func main() {
    s1 := Nearby{
        id:          1,
        me:          1,
        you:         2,
        contactTime: time.Now().String(), // <-- type Time has a String() method
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v", s1)

}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers,